# Why does the golang 1.19.2-bullseye Docker container does not provide correct quoting in Docker output?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, go, sh

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.19.2-bullseye@sha256:2fddf0539591f8e364c9adb3d495d1ba2ca8a8df420ad23b58e7bcee7986ea6c as gobuilder

ARG CGO_ENABLED
ARG CGO_CFLAGS

RUN set -x && \
    printf 'package main\nimport (\n\t"fmt"\n\t"os"\n)\nfunc main(){\n\tfmt.Println(os.Getenv("CGO_CFLAGS"))\n}\n' > main.go && \
    cat main.go && \
    CGO_ENABLED="${CGO_ENABLED}" CGO_CFLAGS="${CGO_CFLAGS}" go build main.go && \
    ls && \
    CGO_CFLAGS="${CGO_CFLAGS}" ./main
```

(Yes I know the `as gobuilder` part in the `FROM` line is not necessary, let's ignore that for the moment.)

When I build this, the `set -x` output does not properly quote the build args:

```
$ docker build -t mre --build-arg CGO_ENABLED=1 --build-arg CGO_CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra' .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.82kB
Step 1/4 : FROM golang:1.19.2-bullseye@sha256:2fddf0539591f8e364c9adb3d495d1ba2ca8a8df420ad23b58e7bcee7986ea6c as gobuilder
 ---> dce494d5814b
Step 2/4 : ARG CGO_ENABLED
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39d4b3dd0c4e
Step 3/4 : ARG CGO_CFLAGS
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bfdf4834ae3b
Step 4/4 : RUN set -x &&     printf 'package main\nimport (\n\t"fmt"\n\t"os"\n)\nfunc main(){\n\tfmt.Println(os.Getenv("CGO_CFLAGS"))\n}\n' > main.go &&     cat main.go &&     CGO_ENABLED="${CGO_ENABLED}" CGO_CFLAGS="${CGO_CFLAGS}" go build main.go &&     ls &&     CGO_CFLAGS="${CGO_CFLAGS}" ./main
 ---> Running in 1936a6076a84
+ printf package main\nimport (\n\t"fmt"\n\t"os"\n)\nfunc main(){\n\tfmt.Println(os.Getenv("CGO_CFLAGS"))\n}\n
+ cat main.go
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func main(){
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("CGO_CFLAGS"))
}
+ CGO_ENABLED=1 CGO_CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra go build main.go
+ ls
bin
main
main.go
src
+ CGO_CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra ./main
-Wall -Wextra
Removing intermediate container 1936a6076a84
 ---> a5c293ba4ba8
Successfully built a5c293ba4ba8
Successfully tagged mre:latest
```

Note that the `main` binary outputs the expected environment variable value, but I expected to see the `CGO_CFLAGS` part to be quoted like `+ CGO_CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra' ./main`. Similarly, I expected this quoting in the `go build` command:

```
+ CGO_ENABLED=1 CGO_CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra' go build main.go
```

For comparison, I tried an example with a different Dockerfile with a different base image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.17.3

ARG ENV_VAR1

RUN set -x && ENV_VAR1="${ENV_VAR1}" ENV_VAR2='hello world' true 'minimal reproducible example'
```

Build output:

```
$ docker build -t mre2 --build-arg ENV_VAR1='foo bar' .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.82kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.17.3
 ---> 9ed4aefc74f6
Step 2/3 : ARG ENV_VAR1
 ---> Running in 182a965d4c83
Removing intermediate container 182a965d4c83
 ---> fc5f7f7f2e01
Step 3/3 : RUN set -x && ENV_VAR1="${ENV_VAR1}" ENV_VAR2='hello world' true 'minimal reproducible example'
 ---> Running in 6ebec9bed99a
+ ENV_VAR1='foo bar' ENV_VAR2='hello world' true 'minimal reproducible example'
Removing intermediate container 6ebec9bed99a
 ---> 5e1901518b51
Successfully built 5e1901518b51
Successfully tagged mre2:latest
```

Note in the line

```
+ ENV_VAR1='foo bar' ENV_VAR2='hello world' true 'minimal reproducible example'
```

both environment variables are quoted as I expected.

I would like help understanding why the quotes are not included in the Docker build based on the `golang:1.19.2-bullseye` base image.

For context, I want to be able to see the quoting in my builds so that I can be sure all my commands are being expanded and quoted by the shell as I expect. But I cannot easily verify this if the quoting is not working.

Comment: The purpose of the quotes is to separate the values so the shell can properly interpret them. Once the shell parses the quoted string, those quotes no longer exist. How and if the quotes are echoed back via `set -x` is up to the particular shell.

Comment: I found what the cause is - `/bin/sh` on the `golang:1.19.2-bullseye` base image is a symlink to `dash`, and `dash` (or at least the version of `dash` on the image) does not provide quotes in `set -x` output in the same way `bash` does.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, I didn't realize the quoting for `set -x` was implementation-defined.

Comment: I found a possible workaround to get the desired quoting in the echoed expanded commands is to use `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` (though of course this only works if `/bin/bash` exists)

Comment: It's also worth noting that `ARG` values are visible in the environment to `RUN` commands (but not the eventual `CMD`), so you don't need to manually set them here.

Answer (score 0):

A better fix would be to not rely on `set -x` to display exactly the format you want. Try something like

```
RUN printf '%s\n' 'package main' \
        'import (' \
        '    "fmt"' \
        '    "os"' \
        ')' \
        'func main(){' \
        '    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("CGO_CFLAGS"))' \
        '}' > main.go && \
    cat main.go && \
    : basically unnecessary && \
    CGO_ENABLED="$CGO_ENABLED" && \
    CGO_FLAGS="$CGO_FLAGS" && \
    printf '%s=\042%s\042\n' \
        CGO_ENABLED "$CGO_ENABLED" \
        CGO_FLAGS "$CGO_FLAGS" && \
    go build main.go && \
    ls && \
    ./main
```

There will be somewhat less output (you could of course put back the `set -x` if you really want to see literally everything; but understand that the output formatting will be shell-dependent) but this way, you have full control over the `printf` to display the variable values in an unambiguous format.

Assigning the `ARG` variables back to themselves is basically unnecessary (as also mentioned in a comment); but I kept them in just to demonstrate how you can set a variable once for the remaining duration of the current `RUN` directive.

(You'll also notice that I refactored the first `printf`. I guess you could get tab indentation in the source file if you really wanted to; but to me, legibility here trumps full control.)